# Seeking Commuting Zones (1990) shapefile?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am hoping to have a shapefile for commuting zones (CZ) for the year 1990 to use in ArcGIS.

Where can I obtain this data?

USDA ERS provides commuting zones and labor market areas for 1990, but it is not in the format of a shapefile. Is there data that follows similar information as their excel file in the shapefile format?

Comment: more information is necessary. commuting zones...of what geographic area? is this a specific dataset from a specific source? urls?

Comment: Of the entire US from the BLS most likely

Comment: again, more information please. and you should add it to your question so everyone can see. assume you mean us bureau of labor statistics. not aware of their commuting zone geo dataset. am aware of usda ers commuting zone geo dataset. clarification in your question would be really helpful.

Comment: This is an international forum. If you make your question understandable for a world wide audience it's probably much better. *USDA*, well OK, but *ERS*? We shouldn't have to go look that up.  Please [read this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Health Inequality Project](https://healthinequality.org/) has [Commuting Zone Boundaries (1990 Definition)](https://healthinequality.org/data/) that look extremely similar to the USDA ERS LMA for 1990. [LMA (Labor Market Area) were used prior to Commuting Zones in 2000](https://www.ers.usda.gov/data-products/commuting-zones-and-labor-market-areas/documentation.aspx).

[image: USDA ERS Labor Market Areas for the United States, 1990]